# java mysql innodb disable transaction

Tags: mysql

how do I disable transaction temporarily if I'm using innodb from java jdbc?  I'm doing a mass insert and wonder if it will speed up things. or should I just set autocommit to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually things will be a bit faster if you perform a mass insert in a single transaction, this is something opposite to setting autocommit to true. Insert will go much faster if you perform it via the ["Handler socket"](http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/2010/10/using-mysql-as-nosql-story-for.html) plugin, latest Percona Server already includes it.

Comment: With large tables that's not true.
In my case it takes 5 days to make a INSERT INTO SELECT * FROM.
If I instead insert in 10k chunks it takes 2 hours.

And the 5 day statement has another problem: If I cancel it there will be a slow rollback takeing weeks to finish.  
The only way to free that table again is to start mysql in crash recovery mode.